# How do we know how -iī and -iit perfects were stressed?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, perfect-tense, stress, syncopated-perfect

The question [Are there exceptions to the Latin stress rules?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/604/9) has an [answer by Joel Derfner](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/602/9) saying that the first-person singular perfect forms *dormiī, audiī, veniī* (for *dormīvī, audīvī, venīvī*) have penult stress, and an [answer by Alex B.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/604/9) saying that contracted perfect forms like *audīt* from *audīvit* or *disturbāt* from *disturbāvit* are supposed to have had ultimate stress.

That sounds plausible to me, but I'm confused because at one point in ["Aspects of the Phonology and
Morphology of Classical Latin" (2016)](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf) Andras Cser says that neither i in *abiit* was stressed (6.2.3.3; p. 121). Cser analyzes *eo* and its compounds as having a perfect stem that underlyingly ends in *ī-* (p. 117), which might be relevant, but I'm not sure whether it is commonly accepted that *audii(t)* and *abiit* had different stress patterns.

Also, Leumann 1977 says "diese Akzentuation perf. *audít cupít fumát* gegenüber praes. *aúdit* usw. ist sicher von Grammatikern differentiae causa für Dichterinterpretation in der Schule festgelegt (vgl. § 237, 1d); also faßten sie *audít* als verkürztes *audīvit*, d. h. als kontrahiertes *audī́it*, nicht *aúdiit*", which if I understand correctly implies that *aúdiit,* with antepenultimate stress, was a form that was actually used (*Lateinische Laut- und Formenlehre,* p. 601).

This made me wonder how we would even know where the stress fell in such words. The "remote past tenses" in Romance languages seem to indicate stress on the *i* (e.g. Italian "[udii](https://forvo.com/search/udii/)" seems to have penult stress), but the position of stress in Italian and other Romance languages isn't always the same as the position of stress in Classical Latin. Is there any other evidence for the stress patterns of these perfect forms in Classical or Pre-Classical Latin?