# Contraction of the v-perfect in the first person singular

Tags: conjugation, contraction

When there is talk about the v-perfect contraction, I don't ever see first person forms used as examples, only forms like "amavisti" becoming "amasti". So my question is whether first person singular forms like "amavi", for example, can be contracted. My guess for this class of conjugation is no, but I feel like for fourth conjugation verbs like audire, "audivi" becoming "audi" (With a long i, I suppose) could work well. Are my guesses correct?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the nice question! I should point out that the perfect form is *amai* in Italian, but that's not really a contraction within Latin.

Comment: “Audii” was used as an alternative form to “audivi”; I researched this while putting together an answer to the following previous question: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/do-contracted-perfects-have-long-or-short-vowels/9353#9353